# Java Selenium chromeDriver console message Error

Tags: java, selenium, ant, junit, selenium-chromedriver

I am using ant to run my selenium test, and I have this message (see pic):

[junit] Error 
[junit] Starting ChromeDriver (v2.xxxxx) on port xxxx

I tried the following properties but without success :

```
options.addArguments("--disable-logging"); 
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors"); 
options.addArguments("--silent");
```

I can disable this message? it's possible ?

Comment: don't put pictures in questions please.. take the code, and paste it into the question

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: I can disable this message? it's possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to pass --silent argument to chromedriver to stop console message. We can achieve this using 'withSilent(true)' method

Launch chromedriver using chromedriverservice as shown in below sample code

Sample Code:

```
            ChromeDriverService cdservice=new ChromeDriverService.Builder().usingDriverExecutable(new File("/path/to/chromedriver.exe"))
                    .withLogFile(new File("/path/to/chromedriver.log"))
                    .withSilent(true)
                    .usingAnyFreePort()
                    .build();

            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cdservice);
            driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

> ```
>     ChromeOptions chromeOptions = setupChromeOptions();
>     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "\\path\\chromedriver.log");
>     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\\path\\chromedriver.exe");
>     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.args", "--disable-logging");
>     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
>     driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
> ```

because
1) This way works for me and
2) the often-reccomended ChromeDriverService.Builder() throws a compile error for me.

This works for me with the following config

> ```
>   selenium-chrome-driver-2.48.2.jar
>   chromedriver 2.20
>   selenium-java-2.48.2.jar
> ```